# Silverlight Button "isWindowless" setting dynamically

Tags: silverlight

I am generating my Silverlight Button through following code.

```
    Silverlight.createObjectEx(
    {
        source: controlSource, 
        parentElement: container,
        id: "ControlId",
        properties: { width: w, height: h, version: "4.0", background: NUSA_recordButtonBackgroundColor, enableHtmlAccess: "true", initParams: params},
        events: { onLoad: onControlLoad }            
    }
```

Here my problem is, when a popup is placed over silverlight button, then the button is ovveriding the popup. Here Z-index is not working properly. "isWindowless" property has to set to true, to make the functionality work properly.

Now, the above code is in Js File which has reference from another location, not from our server.I am just using the reference of the JS file in my page.
In the above method I have to add one more property [isWindowless ='true']

Can anyone tell , how to add property to the existing method in JS file, through the Javascript in my current page
(or)
How to ovveride the existing method through javascript

Comment: Or can anyone tell the possible solution ??

Answer (score 1):

So you cannot change the method in the .js file? [Here is a method](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/crmdevelopment/thread/522c21c1-ca40-4fb2-97ed-ab62bdafbe4c) (not written by me) that refreshes the Silverlight plugin with the same values, and set the Windowless property. It may be a starting point for you...

```
function RefreshSilverlight() {
    var source;
    var initParams;
    var SLControl = window.document.getElementById('WebResource_KBArticleLookup');
    var parent = SLControl.parentNode; 

   for (var i = 0; i < SLControl.childNodes.length; i++) 
   {
       for (var j = 0; j < SLControl.childNodes.item(i).attributes.length; j++) 
       {
          if (SLControl.childNodes.item(i).attributes.item(j).nodeValue == 'source') 
          {
              for (var k = 0; k < SLControl.childNodes.item(i).attributes.length; k++)
              {
                 if (SLControl.childNodes.item(i).attributes.item(k).nodeName == 'value')
                 {
                     source = SLControl.childNodes.item(i).attributes.item(k).nodeValue;
                 }
              }
          }

         if (SLControl.childNodes.item(i).attributes.item(j).nodeValue == 'initParams') 
         {
            for (var k = 0; k < SLControl.childNodes.item(i).attributes.length; k++) 
            {
               if (SLControl.childNodes.item(i).attributes.item(k).nodeName == 'value')
               {
                  initParams = SLControl.childNodes.item(i).attributes.item(k).nodeValue;
               }
            }
         }
      }
    }

    parent.removeChild(SLControl);
    Silverlight.createObject(source,
                             parent,
                             "WebResource_KBArticleLookup",
                             {
                                 width: '800',
                                 height: '600',
                                 windowless: 'true',
                                 enablehtmlaccess: 'true',
                                 minRuntimeVersion: '4.0'
                             },
                             null, initParams, null);
```

}